# Classification algorithm find closest observations

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cart, boosting

I am currently using Light GBM (Gradient Boosting) in Python, but this question can apply to other classification algorithms.

In order to improve my model's explainability I would like to be able to find the top n true positive observations that are closest (most similar) to the predicted positive observation.

There are several common local and global explainability methods that look to explain how the features used in the model impact the prediction, however for my use case the most intuitive explanation to understand the model would be to show the true positive observations that are the most related to the predicted positive observation.

Practically what would be the best way to go about achieving this?

**To clarify with an example:**

I have a training data-set that I use to train a classification algorithm, the objective of the algorithm is to determine if a student will pass or fail a test, the data is labeled with pass=1 and fail=0. After training the algorithm using the training data-set a new observation (student, John) is passed to the algorithm so that it can predict if they will pass or fail.

If the model predicts with a high probability that John will pass, it does so because John's feature-set lays within the "pass" decision boundary. In order to form a decision boundary in the first place an algorithm will need training set observations to learn from. This means that if John is in fact predicted to pass, this only occurs if his features are similar enough to other students who passed seen in the training set.

**What I would like to know is that for a given student John, who is predicted to pass the test, the following students: Susan, Julia, Raymond, Julien are the most related to John and therefore are the basis for which John was predicted to pass.**

Comment: It seems like you want to show the most successful positive classifications. I couldn't merge this idea with explainability.

Comment: Simplest would be to look-up into training set and find the closest instances  (distance-wise) that have the same label. But the question is not clear in terms of explainability, while " similar enough" is ambiguous.

Comment: Why not just look at which observations are often in the same leafs together? Decision trees sort observations according to (1) the value of the features and (2) their outcomes, so you know that the observations that often share the same leaves are very similar according to the model.